# How to filter an ArrayList that has multi members in each element?

Tags: java

I have a function that reads air pollution data from a file and save it to an Array List. I'd like to filter the elements and print out the result.

I'm able to get a row from the ArrayList with `System.out.println("1st element " + pollution.get(0))` but don't know how to apply a filter to a single column.

The data file looks like this

```
shanghai        2015-321   15   15   93.8   16
beijing         2015-332   23   270   86   -1
```

The AirPollution class

```
public class AirPollution {

    private String city;
    private String date;
    private int hour;
    private double pm;             // Particulate matter
    private double humidity;
    private double temperature;

    /** Construct a new AirPollution object */
    public AirPollution(String city, String date, int hour, double pm, double humidity, double temperature) {
        this.city = city;
        this.date = date;
        this.hour = hour;
        this.pm = pm;
        this.humidity = humidity;
        this.temperature = temperature;
    }

    /** Get the PM concentration */
    public double getPM() {return this.pm;}

    public String toString() {
    return this.city + " at " + this.hour + " on " + this.date
    + " Humidity: " + this.humidity + " temperature: " + this.temperature;
    }
}
```

Function that read the file and save it to an Array List

```
public class AirPollutionAnalyser {
    private ArrayList<AirPollution> pollution = new ArrayList<AirPollution>();

    public void loadData() {
       try {
           this.pollution.clear();
           List<String> pollution = Files.readAllLines(Path.of(UIFileChooser.open("pollution.txt")));
           for (String line : pollution) {
               Scanner s = new Scanner(line);
               String city = s.next();
               String date = s.next();
               int hour = s.nextInt();
               double pm = s.nextDouble();
               double humidity = s.nextDouble();
               double temperature = s.nextDouble();
               this.pollution.add(new AirPollution(city, date, hour, pm, humidity, temperature));
            }
           
       } catch(IOException e){UI.println("File reading failed");}
    }
```

Print out all the records in the ArrayList that have a PM2.5 concentration 300 and over.

** This is the function I'd like to make changes to.**

```
    public void findHazardousLevels() {
        UI.clearText();
        UI.println("PM2.5 Concentration 300 and above:");
        UI.println("------------------------");
        System.out.println("1st element " + pollution.get(0))
    }
}
```

How to achieve the result with minimal changes to the current code ?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't clear from your class fields what `PM2.5` is but you can print each entry that has a `pm >= 300` like this.  Since your class fields are private it presumes you have getters to obtain the fields.

```
public void findHazardousLevels() {
    UI.clearText();
    UI.println("PM2.5 Concentration 300 and above:");
    UI.println("------------------------");
    for(AirPollution p : pollution) {
       if (p.getPm() >= 300) { 
           System.out.println(p);
       }
    }
}
```

Note:  Your `toString()` implementation does not have `pm` included in the returned string.

Comment: thank you. Does the "Pollution" in `for (Pollution p : pollution)` suppose to be lowercase ? I tried both upper and lowercase but received error `cannot fine symbol - class pollution`

Comment: @Osca Replace `Pollution`  with `AirPolution`, i.e the type/class of the elements in your `pollution` list. So change it to `for (AirPolution p : pollution)` ....

Comment: @Eritrean  Mea culpa.  I mistakenly specified the wrong name of the class.  I fixed it. 
 Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```java
List.of(
                new AirPollution( "shanghai" , LocalDateTime.of( LocalDate.ofYearDay( 2015 , 321 ) , LocalTime.of( 15 , 0 ) ) , 15 , 93.8 , 16 ) ,
                new AirPollution( "beijing" , LocalDateTime.of( LocalDate.ofYearDay( 2015 , 322 ) , LocalTime.of( 23 , 0 ) ) , 270 , 86 , - 1 )
        )
        .stream()
        .filter(
                sample -> sample.temperature() <= 0
        )
        .toList();
```

> [AirPollution[city=beijing, when=2015-11-18T23:00, particulate_2_5=270.0, humidity=86.0, temperature=-1.0]]

## Details

For a simple solution using classic syntax, see the correct [Answer by WJS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68186865/642706). For a fancier but not necessarily better solution, read on.

### Filtering a stream

You can easily filter a `List` by using modern streams and lambda syntax.

#### Records

By the way, in Java 16 you can abbreviate your class definition by using the [records](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395) feature. The compiler implicitly creates the constructor, getters, `equals` & `hashCode`, and `toString`.

#### *java.time*

FYI, Java has classes in the *java.time* framework to represent your date and time-of-day: [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html), [`LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalTime.html), and combining those two, [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html). The `LocalDate` class offers the [`ofYearDay`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html#ofYearDay(int,int)) method to handle your day-of-year input.

Here is your entire class:

```java
package work.basil.demo;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;

public record AirPollution( String city , LocalDateTime when , double particulate_2_5 , double humidity , double temperature ) { }
```

Instantiate a few.

```java
List < AirPollution > samples =
        List.of(
                new AirPollution( "shanghai" , LocalDateTime.of( LocalDate.ofYearDay( 2015 , 321 ) , LocalTime.of( 15 , 0 ) ) , 15 , 93.8 , 16 ) ,
                new AirPollution( "beijing" , LocalDateTime.of( LocalDate.ofYearDay( 2015 , 322 ) , LocalTime.of( 23 , 0 ) ) , 270 , 86 , - 1 )
        );
```

Access your list as a stream, to process each element. Call `Stream#filter` to skip over the elements that flunk your predicate test. Collect passing elements into a new list.

```java
List < AirPollution > freezing = samples.stream().filter( sample -> sample.temperature() <= 0 ).toList();
```

In older versions prior to Java 16, you will need to replace that `.toList()` call with `.collect( Collectors.toList() )`.

Here is complete demo code.

```java
package work.basil.demo;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.util.List;

public class AirPollutionDemo
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        List < AirPollution > samples =
                List.of(
                        new AirPollution( "shanghai" , LocalDateTime.of( LocalDate.ofYearDay( 2015 , 321 ) , LocalTime.of( 15 , 0 ) ) , 15 , 93.8 , 16 ) ,
                        new AirPollution( "beijing" , LocalDateTime.of( LocalDate.ofYearDay( 2015 , 322 ) , LocalTime.of( 23 , 0 ) ) , 270 , 86 , - 1 )
                );

        List < AirPollution > freezing = samples.stream().filter( sample -> sample.temperature() <= 0 ).toList();

        System.out.println( "samples = " + samples );
        System.out.println( "freezing = " + freezing );
    }
}
```

When run.

> samples = [AirPollution[city=shanghai, when=2015-11-17T15:00, particulate_2_5=15.0, humidity=93.8, temperature=16.0], AirPollution[city=beijing, when=2015-11-18T23:00, particulate_2_5=270.0, humidity=86.0, temperature=-1.0]]
>
> freezing = [AirPollution[city=beijing, when=2015-11-18T23:00, particulate_2_5=270.0, humidity=86.0, temperature=-1.0]]

Comment: thank you so much for spending the time to answer my question. Sadly I only have learnt java for two weeks so many parts of your code I don't quite understand. I'll re-read them in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You have a list of objects which have fields, not "columns", you'd loop over them, and write some if-statement to exclude/find data you are interested in

If you convert the list to a stream, you can call `filter().findFirst()` and get it, if available

```
Predicate<AirPollution> highPm = p -> p.getPM() > 300;

Optional<AirPollution> opt = pollution.stream().filter(highPM).findFirst();

if (opt.isPresent()) {
    System.out.println(opt.get());
} else {
    System.out.println("No high PM found");
}
```